# How to get complete path of files that are being searched within a folder in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My folder structure is as follows:
[image: Folder Structure]

I want to get the paths of all files that contain the string xyz. The result must be as:

- folder/folderA/fileA2
- folder/folderB/fileB1
- folder/file1

I tried this:

```
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(folderTestPath):
    for file in files:
        if "xyz" in open(folderTestPath+file,'r'):
             print (os.path.abspath(file))
```

folderTestPath contains the path of the folder. This code only gives me the file names followed by a file not found error. I know this is a simple thing, but for some reason am unable to get it. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **[os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)** method:

```
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(folderTestPath):
    for file in files:
        filePath = os.path.join(path, file)
        if "xyz" in open(filePath ,'r').read():
             print("xyz")
             print(filePath)
```

*As Eric mentioned to close the file after reading it use the below snippet*:

```
import os

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(folderTestPath):
    for file in files:
        filePath = os.path.join(path, file)
        with open(filePath ,'r') as data:
            if "xyz" in data.read():
                print("xyz")
                print(filePath)
        data.close()
```

Comment: The final `.close()` method seems to be redundant when you use ’with' Context Manager block.